# Using async function inside non async function in flutter

Tags: flutter

i have a question,

I have a custom class, which has a constructor. One of the parameters of the constructor is a function. so i call it like this:
`TableWidget(table_number: "Table 1", iconcolor: getColor("Table 1", _DateSelectTable.getvalue())),`.
The getColor function is not async, but inside that function i want to open a file using path provider, which is async. How can i make this work without getting errors?

**Thanks a lot**

*Edit: added the getColor function code:

```
getColor(tableNumber, date) {
  final File file = File('assets/states1.txt');
  lines = file.readAsLinesSync(encoding: utf8);
  for(var line in lines){
    if(line.substring(0, 7) == tableNumber){
      if(line.substring(13, 15) == "${date.day}"){
        return Colors.red;
      }
    }
  }
  return Colors.black;
}
```

What i want to do here and the reason why i am asking you is that instead of have the path to the file as **'assets/states1.txt'** i want to use the get documents directory function, which is async. thank you.

Comment: Can you share the getColor Function please?

Comment: So we can view the code?

Comment: I just added the getColor function code.

Comment: I don't think you can use it like this. If you call an asynchronous function from a normal one which depends upon the result of asynchronous function then your normal function becomes asynchronous. i.e Your getColor is an async function as well.
You can call getColor in loop before calling TableWidget and store the getColor result then only render the TableWidget. 
Hope I am clear. If you can show how is yout TableWidget is called then i might be able to help with the actual code.

Answer (score -1):

so I let's put this as example because you didn't put that getColor function

```
getColor(...) {
    // your normal function 
  }
```

what I understand is that you want to call an asynchronous function insidz of it, let's say getFile(), you can put it like this

```
 getColor(...) async {
    // your normal function 

    await getFile();
  }
```

you can add the async keyword to your function and it will work normally, and you can put inside of it an asynchronous function that will until it will be done.

Comment: I just added the getColor function code.

Comment: when doing it the way you suggested. i get this error: type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Color'.

Comment: check my other answer

Comment: now i get that error on the constructor: The argument type 'Future<Color>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Color' and when i use it as await getColor... i get : The await expression can only be used in an async function.
Try marking the function body with either 'async' or 'async*'

Comment: @Gwhyyy your answer should work as the function is not asynchronous because its type void not Future<void>, so you dont have to put await in front of getColor method, even there is async keyword

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
Future<Color> getColor(tableNumber, date) async{
  Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
  final File file =   File(tempDir.path);
  lines = file.readAsLinesSync(encoding: utf8);
  for(var line in lines){
    if(line.substring(0, 7) == tableNumber){
      if(line.substring(13, 15) == "${date.day}"){`enter code here`
        return Colors.red;
      }
    }
  }
  return Colors.black;
}
```